# How to use Android setColorFilter() with ValueAnimator reliably

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to modify the colour of a BitmapDrawable being used as a Button background. I need to use setColorFilter(), so I believe I need to use a ValueAnimator and call setColorFilter() within the AnimatorUpdateListener, as below:

```
final Integer colorFrom = G.actResources.getColor(R.color.TS_Orange); // color to fade from
final Integer colorTo = G.actResources.getColor(R.color.white); // color to fade to
final Button brow = ...; // get my Button object
final Drawable bd = brow.getBackground(); // get my BitmapDrawable
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        Integer i = (Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue();
        if (i == colorTo)
            bd.clearColorFilter();
        else
            bd.setColorFilter(i, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

          brow.invalidate(); // What do I need to do here, to ensure the View is updated?
    }
});
```

My problem is that the animation sometimes works, and sometimes does not. The only completely reliable way I have found of ensuring the animation appears as expected is to call requestLayout() on the enclosing ViewGroup, within the animation listener callback. But of course this is VERY slow, making the animation run at about 2 fps.

So what is the most lightweight way of ensuring the UI system redraws the View with the updated colour? I've tried View.invalidate(), Drawable.invalidateSelf(), and pretty much everything I can think of.

It's worth noting that, whilst calling requestLayout() on the enclosing ViewGroup within the animation listener callback has always been slow on most Samsung devices, it USED to be very fast on Nexus 4 etc. However since the Android 4.4.3 update it's become slowest of all on Nexus 4!

Comment: To add some more info - this is actually not related to setColorFilter(). I have tried other ways of modifying the View, and I see the same results; the onAnimationUpdate() method is getting called as expected, but the View appearance is not changing.

Comment: did you try for testing purposes to use a Handler.postDelayed and check if it works the same slow?

Comment: OK I've tracked this down as follows... The Button I am trying to animate sits within a ViewGroup that is itself animated on/off the screen using straight View animation (i.e. specifying a <translate> animation in XML).

The View animation is working fine, but what happens is that (sometimes only) when the View has scrolled on, the Buttons inside it don't respond to the ValueAnimator. If I turn off the View animation (i.e. the scrolling on), then the Buttons reliably DO respond to the ValueAnimator.

Comment: But the Buttons always look correct when the View is scrolled on, and before the ValueAnimator starts. So the Android UI framework has them in the right place. So why is my ValueAnimator's call to setColorFilter(), or setBackgroundColor(), or whatever else I try, not reliably updating the Button View if the enclosing ViewGroup had a View animation?

Comment: try to add this http://pastebin.com/1Cj4YFLy in onCreate and see how it looks like